# Lazy load in RoR App (paginate results)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lazy-loading

I want to realize some kind of lazy loading in my rails app. That means I have a query result of about 50 000 lines. I want them to be shown on 50 pages with 100 lines each. 
I can't load all the data before because it makes my browser crashing down.

So how do I just load a part of my data at a time? 
Does anyone can tell me some keywords that I can google?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the will_paginate gem for this functionality: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

It allows you to do things like `@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page])` in the controller and `<%= will_paginate @posts %>` in the view.

Comment: Also worth considering the Kaminari gem, which I prefer slightly to will_paginate.  Or roll your own using the `limit` and 'offset` operators in Rails' ActiveRecord query interface.  The keyword you want is probably "pagination" or "paginate", not "lazy load", which means something a little different (load data only when needed, automatically).

Comment: thanks so much! I was searching for that! Pagination makes sense :D